# display highest value

Tags: java, sql, arrays

I have written a function which is used to pick the highest value and display everything from sql based on the ID. If aa[0] is highest it will display everything in ID 0, if not, it will display either 1 or 2. But the problem now is it only displays value in ID 0 although ID 1 is the highest! Anyone can help me to figuring out what;s wrong with my coding ? Thanks

```
  private void pick_highest_value_here_and_display(ArrayList<Double> value) throws Exception {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 double aa[]=value.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v.doubleValue()).toArray(); 
                 double highest=aa[0]; 
                 if(highest==aa[0])
                 {
                     String sql ="Select * from placeseen where ID =0";
                     DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
                     Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
                     PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                     if (rs.next()) 
                     {  
                      String aaa=rs.getString("place1");  
                      String bbb=rs.getString("place2");
                      String cc=rs.getString("place3");
                      Tourism to =new Tourism();
                      to.setPlace1(aaa);
                      to.setPlace2(bbb);
                      to.setPlace3(cc);
                      DispDay dc=new DispDay();
                      dc.setVisible(true);
                     }
                     ps.close();
                     rs.close();
                     conn.close();
             }   else
             {
                  for(int i=0;i<aa.length;i++)
                 {
                     if(aa[i]>highest)
                     {
                         highest=aa[i];
                         System.out.println(highest);
                         String sql ="Select * from placeseen where ID =?";
                         DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
                         Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
                         PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                         ps.setDouble(1, i); 
                         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                         if (rs.next()) 
                         {  
                          String aaa=rs.getString("place1");  
                          String bbb=rs.getString("place2");
                          String cc=rs.getString("place3");
                          Tourism to =new Tourism();
                          to.setPlace1(aaa);
                          to.setPlace2(bbb);
                          to.setPlace3(cc);
                          DispDay dc=new DispDay();
                          dc.setVisible(true);
                         }
                         ps.close();
                         rs.close();
                         conn.close();
                 }   

                 }

             }
```

Comment: The problem with your function has nothing to do with SQL.  The problem with your logic is that you are doing the work in java, rather than in the database where it would be much more efficient.

Comment: I agree with Gordon however you are setting highest to aa[0] then checking to see if highest = aa[0] which will always be true therefore never getting to your else.

Comment: "Get this thing. Okay, now the highest I've found is that thing. If that thing is the highest, do this... else, loop some stuff"

Comment: How should I write so that the condition can work? The double aa[] actually holding three values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void pick_highest_value_here_and_display(ArrayList<Double> value) throws Exception {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             double aa[]=value.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v.doubleValue()).toArray(); 
             double highest=aa[0]; 
              for(int i=1;i<aa.length;i++)
             {
                 if(aa[i]>highest)
                 {
                     highest=aa[i];
                     System.out.println(highest);
                     String sql ="Select * from placeseen where ID =?";
                     DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
                     Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
                     PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                     ps.setDouble(1, i); 
                     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                     if (rs.next()) 
                     {  
                      String aaa=rs.getString("place1");  
                      String bbb=rs.getString("place2");
                      String cc=rs.getString("place3");
                      Tourism to =new Tourism();
                      to.setPlace1(aaa);
                      to.setPlace2(bbb);
                      to.setPlace3(cc);
                      DispDay dc=new DispDay();
                      dc.setVisible(true);
                     }
                     ps.close();
                     rs.close();
                     conn.close();
             }  
                 else if(highest==aa[0])
                 {
                     String sql ="Select * from placeseen where ID =0";
                     DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
                     Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
                     PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                     if (rs.next()) 
                     {  
                      String aaa=rs.getString("place1");  
                      String bbb=rs.getString("place2");
                      String cc=rs.getString("place3");
                      Tourism to =new Tourism();
                      to.setPlace1(aaa);
                      to.setPlace2(bbb);
                      to.setPlace3(cc);
                      DispDay dc=new DispDay();
                      dc.setVisible(true);
                     }
                     ps.close();
                     rs.close();
                     conn.close();
                 }


         }


             }
```